# undefined method ` ' for API::V1::Projects:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-grape

I am trying to setup grape api. While I'm including defaults module:

```
 module API
  module V1
    module Defaults
      extend ActiveSupport::Concern
      included do
        version 'v1'
        format :json
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the error undefined method ` ' for API::V1::Projects:Class occurs. Also, when I paste

```
version 'v1'
format :json
```

to classes without doing mixin, it works. My operating system is Mac OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `format :json` line is indented by both, normal spaces and [en spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Width_variations).

Inspecting the line's code points reveals them:

```
line = "        format :json"
line.codepoints
#=> [8194, 32, 8194, 32, 8194, 32, 8194, 32, 102, 111, 114, 109, 97, 116, 32, 58, 106, 115, 111, 110]
#    ^         ^         ^         ^
```

Replacing the en spaces with normal spaces should fix the problem.